# How to put stopping condition for recursive sql?

Tags: sql, database, recursion, db2, recursive-query

```
with closure (obj_1, obj_2) as (
 SELECT distinct t.obj_1, t.obj_2 
   FROM temp4 t
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT c.obj_1, t.obj_2 
   FROM closure c, temp4 t 
   WHERE c.obj_2=t.obj_1)
SELECT * FROM closure
```

This runs infinitely because there are cycles in the data, is there a way to add a stopping condition in this statement so if the row already exists in closure, I want it to stop recursing for that row.

Comment: You need to keep track of the objects visited and use that information to stop the processing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you reference an example or a document explaining this possibly? I'm completely new to this and would be great to see something I can try out.

Comment: . . I have done this in SQL Server, but not in DB2.  One idea is to keep the object ids in a string (and other column) and check that the ids have not been used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you show the example using sql server just so I can understand it logistically?

Comment: Good info including an example of coping with cycles https://gist.github.com/felixyz/fcc90efc53c81d0b4b9c

Answer (score 1):

This example limits the loops to 100 - I think you get the idea:

```
with closure (obj_1, obj_2, counter) as (
 SELECT distinct t.obj_1, t.obj_2 , 1 
   FROM temp4 t
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT c.obj_1, t.obj_2, counter + 1 
   FROM closure c, temp4 t 
  WHERE c.obj_2=t.obj_1
    AND counter <= 100)
SELECT * FROM closure
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps with the infinite loop problem, but I need my stopping condition to be of the sort: if closure already contains (obj_1, obj_2) then don't stop. I need this to prevent cycles.

Comment: even better, is there a way I can specify for the 2nd part of the UNION ALL to not include the current row that it is recursing on to prevent cycles?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to build up a query helper, something like this

```
with closure (obj_1, obj_2) as (
 SELECT distinct t.obj_1, t.obj_2,convert(varchar(30),t.obj_1)+';' as treePath
   FROM temp4 t
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT c.obj_1, t.obj_2 convert(varchar(30),t.obj_2)+';' as treePath
   FROM closure c, temp4 t
   WHERE c.obj_2=t.obj_1
and charindex(';' + convert(varchar(30),t.obj_2)+';',treepath,1)=0
SELECT * FROM closure
```